# Filtered data inside sliderInput() in shiny?

Tags: r, filter, shiny, filtering, word-cloud

I have a sliderInput() which the max value I would like to be changed based on the users input. I am trying to create a wordcloud and the code for the wordcloud is working, just my slider need adjustments. So my dataset looks like this:

```
document   term    count
1          code    1
1          help    28
1          stupid  4
1          shock   7
2          fire    2
2          fly     9
2          money   1
2          free    3
.          .       .
.          .       .
20
```

What I want is that my max value inside the sliderInput() function should be automatically setted with the highest count of a selected document. So the user can select between different documents "1", "2", till "20". Based on the selection the max count should be assigned to the max value of the sliderInput(). In my example: If selecting document 1 -> max value = 28. If selecting document 2 -> max value = 9. I have a filtered function which I use in the server.R. If I could use this function inside the ui.R my problem is solved but its not allowed using functions from server insider ui. How can I solve this problem?

Code ui.R:

```
        # Select document
        box(
          title = "Document Control",
          status = "primary",
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          width = 4,
          selectInput("doc", label="Select Document", choices = c(1:20), selected = 1)
        ),

        # Slider
        box(
          title = "Frequency Control",
          status = "primary",
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          width = 4,
          height = 142,
          sliderInput("minFreq", label = "Minimum Frequency", min = 1, max = ... , value = 15)
        ),

            box(
              title = "Number Control",
              status = "primary",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              width = 4,
              height = 142,
              sliderInput("maxNum", label = "Maximum Number of Words", min = 1, max = 400, value = 150)

            ),
```

Server code:

```
  filtered <- reactive({
    Wcloud.Data.filtered <- Wcloud.Data %>%
      filter(document == input$doc)
  }) 

  output$plotWcloud <- renderPlot({

    wordcloud(words = filtered()$term, freq = filtered()$count, 
              min.freq = input$minFreq, max.words = input$maxNum, random.order=FALSE, 
              rot.per=0.35, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))

  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sliderInput` is **created in the server** function with a `renderUI`.
Every time you reload the app, a new dataset is created and the slider updates min/max/ and takes the 5 value of the data.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("slider")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$slider <- renderUI({
    data = round(runif(10, 1, 100),2)
    sliderInput("sliderInp", label = "Select a value", min = min(data), max = max(data), value = data[5])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Implemented in your example would result in:

ui:

```
# Select document
box(
  title = "Document Control",
  status = "primary",
  solidHeader = TRUE,
  width = 4,
  selectInput("doc", label="Select Document", choices = c(1:20), selected = 1)
),

# Slider
box(
  title = "Frequency Control",
  status = "primary",
  solidHeader = TRUE,
  width = 4,
  height = 142,
  uiOutput("slider")
),
```

server:

```
filtered <- reactive({
  Wcloud.Data.filtered <- Wcloud.Data %>%
    filter(document == input$doc)
}) 

output$slider <- renderUI({
  sliderInput("minFreq", label = "Minimum Frequency", min = min(filtered()), max = max(filtered()), value = 15)
})

output$plotWcloud <- renderPlot({
  wordcloud(words = filtered()$term, freq = filtered()$count, 
            min.freq = input$minFreq, max.words = input$maxNum, random.order=FALSE, 
            rot.per=0.35, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
})
```

Comment: thanks for your idea. Is their a solution when the slider is inside the ui.R ? I build a very big dashboard so it has to be inside ui.R. Or how can I implement your idea into my code? Dont understand your suggestion that well

Comment: You could also use `updateSliderInput`, but I prefer creating the slider in the server. In the example you can see that instead of a `sliderInput` there is now a `uiOutput` in the ui. In the server there is a `renderUI` function, which will create the slider with min/max values based on the data. I'll edit my answer, so that it fits your example.

Comment: Perfecccttt man! You are a genies. Thank you very much. One error I fixed my self. Instead of `min(filtered())` we have to used `min(filtered()$count)` and also for the max value. Now its working! Thank you so much

Comment: Is it also possible to do this for the max numbers slider? I tried it with the same code but the problem is term is characters and not words. Tried with count() function but couldnt handle it.

Comment: What max numbers slider? The min & max of the `sliderInput` are created dynamically already. Do you mean for `max.words = input$maxNum` ?

Comment: Yes `max.words = input$maxNum`. Can I also do this for max.words? based on selected documents count the words that are for this document and put it also inside the `max.words` slider. See my code I insert the `maxNum` box.

Comment: Yes you can use `renderUI` and `uiOutput` for any shiny-inputs. Same procedure ;)

Comment: Yes I know, but the column does not has numbers now, they are words (character). So how can I count them?

Comment: You are a genie! Thanks bro! worked perfect. Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate.